# Why does my count is coming 1 instead calculating all the digits in the number in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, division

I am trying to calculate the number of digits in a random number, for example for number 5675, I am expecting a count value 4 as an output but instead of that , it's returning 1. I have tried to write the logic in a while loop until the condition satisfied.
Below is my code.

```
class Solution(object):

    def calculate(self, num):
        count_no = 0
        while num > 0:
            num = num / 10
            count_no += 1
            return count_no


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Solution()
    no = 5675
    print(p.calculate(no))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is right but You put `return count_no` in the while loop.
So it will returns in the first iteration, and will not continue till the end of your loop.
do this:

```
def calculate(self, num):
    count_no = 0
    while num > 0:
        num = num // 10
        count_no += 1

    return count_no
```

take a look at [this link](https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3) to learn about blocks in python.

Thanks to @Aurora19, Please chnage `/` to `//` for integer division.

Comment: The answer is coming 328 if I use your code.

Comment: I suggest an edit, chnage the / operator to //.

Comment: @Aurora19 You are definitely right. thanks for  the comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple bugs in your code.

1. What Mehrdad Pedramfar said. You return in the first loop iteration, while you should only return once you exit the loop.
2. Have a look at the value of num in each iteration. If you add `print(num)` to your loop, you'll see something like

```
5675
567.5
56.75
5.675
.5675
```

Not what you expected, right? That's because you're using the true division operator (`/`) instead of the integer division operator (`//`)

3. What's the point of the class? If you don't need a class, don't use one. Also, calling a method `calculate` is just bad. Call it something like `number_of_digits`.

Since this is a school assignment, I leave putting it all together to you.

Comment: Thank you and i also wanted to ask ,how to make IDE (PyCharm in my case) discern if i am returning on first loop iteration or i am exiting the loop because Python doesn't have curly braces and it gets difficult as a begineer in Python to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your solution is the return inside the while loop, in this way the value of `counto_no` is returned at the first iteration which is always 1. You have also to use the integer divider instead of the normale one, the integer divider is this: `//`.

Another solution to your problem can be the following:

```
def countDigit(self,num:int) -> int:
    return len(str(num))
```